# A formula involving the projection of the orthocenter onto a median

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

I found out this problem when I was trying to solve another geometry problem but I stuck to solve it. Please help me. Thanks

Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle with $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$, $AK$ be the altitude from vertex $A$ and $H$ be the orthocenter. $I$ be the projection of $H$ on $AM$.

Prove that $MC^2 = MI. MA $.

[image]

Comment: I am in agreement, stated in my hint and comments.

Comment: @ anonimo: Can you please state how you isolated this question from another geometry problem?

Comment: @Narasimham I've edited my question so it's another one now. You can edit your answer or please feel free to post another one. Thank you very much.

Comment: Changing the goal post? Ok, please include a sketch.

Comment: Included. Thank you for your reminder.

Comment: HINT: (New question) Show that MC is tangent to circle through CIA at C.

Comment: Another occurence of this point I is to be found on page 9 Exercise 3.3 of this [document](https://www.awesomemath.org/wp-pdf-files/math-reflections/mr-2017-02/article_1_a_special_point_on_the_median.pdf)

Comment: @Narasimhan Your question finds an answer in the property of the power of a point $M$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The triangles $BAK$ and $HCK$ are similar because rotating $BAK$ by 90° gives a triangle which three sides are parallel to the sides of $HCK$. It follows that $\frac{BK}{AK} = \frac{HK}{CK}$, or
\begin{equation}AK.KH = BK.CK
\end{equation}

Now the triangles $A I H$ and $A K M$ are similar because they have two equal angles, hence $\frac{AI}{AH} = \frac{AK}{AM}$, hence
\begin{align}
AM.MI &= AM^2 - AM.AI\\
 &= AM^2 - AK.AH\\
 &= AM^2 - AK(AK-KH)\\
 &= MK^2 + BK.CK\\
 &=MK^2 + (MC-MK)(MC+MK)\\
 &= MC^2
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, we only need to assume that AB < AC to have BK.CK = (MC - MK)(MC + MK)

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

The position of A on radical axis is arbitrary. Not clear how the scenario of the power of two coaxal circles, equaling the square of three red segments could help. H is the concurrent point at center.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint, I still wonder if there is a simpler solution based on similarity of triangle.

Comment: Yes, I could n't go further on this route, so put the rough sketch  here fwiw.

Comment: If A goes up or down, the power varies but $BM.MC$ is constant !